# How can I cold-boot a mac with FileVault enabled without physical access to the mac?

Tags: macos, startup, filevault

If I had a Linux machine, I'd be able to enter the password for the encrypted boot disk in a serial terminal during the boot process, via another machine connected to the serial port I can SSH into.

Is there a way I can do this with macOS as well?

Or is there maybe another setup that allows me to unlock FileVault during boot remotely?

Answer (score 0):

You can reboot the system without requiring password entry using the `fdesetup` utility:

```
sudo fdesetup authrestart
```

See `man fdesetup` for details.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately that doesn't work for cold boots, just reboots.